# What is the difference between for each and for_each?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I took over an old code and need to use JNI calls. In the code, I saw the usage of `for each( in )`, but this code cannot be compiled under Linux.

I really want to know how `for each` is generated, which platforms can be used, whether there are any when compiling under Linux?

I am trying to understand the syntax for `for each`, but this information is almost impossible to find, but there are a lot of `for_each` usage.

On the Windows platform, I only used `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)` to compile successfully, and the version after v14 is abnormal.

Under the Linux platform, I use the following command to compile and it throws a lot of errors. The result is as follows:

```
g++ -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191/include/ -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191/include/linux/ -fPIC -shared -o ErmjJNI.so *.cpp -pthread -std=c++11
```

---

```
ErmjAI.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void ErmjAI::initGame(size_t, size_t, const std::vector<std::vector<int> >&, std::string, std::string)’:
ErmjAI.cpp:74:8: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘each’
    for each (size_t tile in tiles[i])
        ^
ErmjAI.cpp:74:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘tile’
    for each (size_t tile in tiles[i])
                     ^
ErmjAI.cpp:74:37: error: ‘each’ was not declared in this scope
    for each (size_t tile in tiles[i])
                                     ^
ErmjAI.cpp:75:4: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
    {
    ^
ErmjAI.cpp:3346:1: error: expected primary-expression at end of input
 }
```

I have queried the relevant API on this (http://www.cplusplus.com/search.do?q=for+each) website but it has no gains.

There is so much code like this, I am already losing my patience, and a few examples are listed below.

```cpp
for each (size_t tile in tiles[i])
{
    if (tile<=33)
    {
        tNum[tile]++;
        _unseen_tiles_num[tile]--;
    }
    else
    {
        m_vecHua[i].push_back(tile);
    }
}
```

- I am eager to know how to compile the `for each` grammar under Linux.
- I want to know the history and usage platform of `for each`.
- I want to know more about how I should understand this, instead of asking questions like now.

Comment: With `#define each` and `#define in :`, you might get this running but I'm afraid it may break other code. ;-)

Comment: replace it one by one , #define is dangerous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`for each, in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in?view=vs-2019) is a non-standard syntax in the Microsoft compiler that even they don't recommend using. I suggest you change the code to use a C++11 [ranged-based for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop. That will be supported by standard conformant compilers.

```
for (size_t tile : tiles[i])
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for each (size_t tile in tiles[i])
```

doesn't look like C++, change it to:

```cpp
for (size_t tile : tiles[i])
```

You can also [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) how range-based for works in C++.